# Why is Excel re-executing functions in the same and different workbook when I create a new UDF and assign it to a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks open.
In workbook A I have some UDFs assigned to cells and in workbook B I have some UDFs assigned to cells.  These have already been executed, so the cells have values. 
In workbook B (i.e. in the VBE) I create a new UDF, call it bar:

```
Function bar()
    bar = "bar"
End Function
```

When I then go into Excel and assign bar() to a cell in workbook B (with `=bar()`) and then hit Enter, the UDFs in both the same workbook and in the other open workbook (workbook A) are triggered. They are re-executed, despite already having been executed and the cells having been populated with values.

Why is this?  It's bizarre and very annoying behaviour even in my tiny little practice workbooks.  What if I had 100 UDFs in a workbook? As soon as I add a new UDF and assign it to a cell, all the UDFs would be triggered.

I am using Excel 2016. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Excel recalculates all cells any time you change something. It's making sure that your change didn't affect any other cells.  If you don't want it to happen, you can switch to manual calculation. I suspect someone will suggest changing the `Volatile` setting for these functions so they only calculate once, but it's not a good idea. Maybe you should use a Sub to populate these cells once, instead of Functions, which are meant to be dynamic.

Comment: That was quick, thank you. But how do I make a UDF calculated manually, and does that mean the UDF won't be calculated when I hit enter after assigning to a cell the first time?

Comment: Calculation is basically either Automatic or Manual for the entire workbook, so this will not just include UDF's. Why is it a problem to calculate everything repeatedly? This is normal behavior and not a problem for properly written functions. With the example you gave, you could put that function in a million cells and you wouldn't even notice it recalculating anytime a cell was changed. See [this](https://support.office.com/article/change-formula-recalculation-iteration-or-precision-f38c7793-0367-41ce-b892-dfe54946bd76) and [this](https://support.microsoft.com/help/214395) for more info.

Comment: It's a problem because the UDF is prompting me for input. This is just me learning VBA, and as per my book I've just been creating trivial functions, some of which take user input.  So when I create a new UDF, I am getting prompted for user input again.  I suppose in real life you'd probably not prompt for user input in a function; maybe it would be a button; I don't know. But as it is I have these UDFs that prompt for input and they keep getting retriggered when I add a function. Perhaps if I weren't developing the spreadsheet it wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @ashleedawg Hang on, according to https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/volatile-functions.html "By default, UDF's (User Defined Functions) in Excel VBA are not volatile. They are only recalculated when any of the function's arguments change."  If this is the case, why are my UDFs, which simply for example launch an InputBox eg `Length = InputBox("Enter Length ", "Enter a Number")` being triggered?

Comment: Then perhaps consider using helper cells for your input. I strongly dislike the idea of placing inputboxes inside of your UDFs - basically defeats the purpose of it being a UDF. If you don't want to use helper cells, then @ashleedawg's suggestion of changing them to a `Sub` is probably the route to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your issue is that you are placing `InputBox()` functions inside your UDF. While you can certainly do this, it essentially defeats the purpose of using a UDF to begin with.

Consider placing an argument inside your UDF that pulls the data from the worksheet instead of you prompting for the user's input every time recalc occurs. Or make a global variable that will remain active while the worksheet is open.

## Using UDF Arguments

If you had a UDF that looked like this:

```
Public Function myUDF()
    Dim myInput As String
    myInput = InputBox("Type Something")
    myUDF = myInput & "!"
End Function
```

You could add an argument that will pull your `myInput` from the worksheet instead:

```
Public Function myUDF(myInput As String) As String
    myUDF = myInput & "!"
End Function
```

Which on your worksheet, would look like this:

```
=myUDF(A1)  'Where A1 is your new `myInput` argument
```

## Using Global Variables

You can also use a global variable that will get your input only when you want to change it. Perhaps you can create a command button that you will press to prompt for your input, or if you only need to prompt it one time - you could use the `Workbook_Open()` event to set this variable - or a combination of both.

So at the top of a **standard** module, you could add your global variable:

```
Public glbVarStr As String
```

And then you would just run any `Sub` to set your global variable:

```
' Since this is a WORKBOOK event, you would need to place this sub in
' your workbook's code module
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    glbVarStr = Inputbox("Type Something")
End Sub
```

which you would then add to your UDF:

```
Public Function myUDF() As String
    myUDF = glbVarStr & "!"
End Function
```